# free() not deallocating memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, free

```
free(str);
printf("%d\n", str->listeners);
```

The call to printf succeeds (as do any other calls to str's members). How is this possible?

Comment: what did you expect would happen?

Comment: What have you done with `str` before?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/11683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just (un)lucky. That code exhibits undefined behavior - anything can happen, including looking like the memory wasn't freed.

The memory *is* freed, but there is no point in actively clearing it, so its original content is likely to still be there. But you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an analogy for you: imagine you're renting an apartment (that's the memory) and you terminate your lease but keep a duplicate of the key (that's the pointer). You *might* be able to get back into the apartment later if it hasn't been torn down, if the locks haven't been changed, etc. and if you do it right away you *might* find things the way you left them. But it's a pretty bad idea, and in the likely case you're going to get yourself in a heap of trouble...

Answer (score 2):

That is called undefined behavior.  You are dereferencing a pointer which refers to deallocated memory. Anything can happen, i.e., one cannot assume that the program will crash or anything else; the behavior is **undefined**.

Answer (score 1):

as long as `str` is not `NULL` and the corresponding memory has not been overwritten by some other allocation it it still works because the memory content is not changed by `free` (if the runtime doesn't overwrite the memory area on `free`). BUT this is definetly undefined behaviour and you CANNOT rely on it to work this way...

Comment: Well, it *could* be changed by `free()`.  The point is that the behavior of this program is undefined.

Comment: @EdS. which is what I wrote in the last sentence!

Comment: You added that after the fact.  I downvoted your original post.  If you don't want downvotes don't rush it :)  Downvote removed

Comment: @EdS. if keeping to edit my own post within the first minute or so is "after the fact" then I am guilty...

Comment: Well... yeah :D.  I saw your original answer before you made the edit.  What other information do I have to go on?  Should I assume that you will edit it sometime in the future to be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Things to keep in mind...

- On virtually all current operating systems, `free()` never returns
  memory to the operating system. Even if it's theoretically capable of
  that, it would almost never actually happen. This is because memory can
  only be returned in aligned pages of, generally, 4kB, because that's how
  the MMU works, and, should one be found, ripping it out would likely
  fragment a block that included memory above and below it, making the
  entire process counterproductive. (Fragmentation is the enemy of     efficient use of dynamic memory.)
- Also, most program just generally
  use more memory, so the time spent searching for something to really
  return to the OS would be totally wasted. If it's not given back to the 
  OS and then protected, it won't core your program when you touch it.
- So instead, what happens is
  that the block you gave to free is just put on a list or some other
  data structure, then possibly merged into blocks above or below it.
- The memory is still there and accessible. Some of the block may be
  overwritten with pointers and other internals of the library code
  behind malloc() and free(). But it might not be.
- Eventually it may be
  handed back elsewhere in your program. But it might not be.